# Script sql in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d not executed

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I try to initialize my postgresql database using sql script in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d folder

I have no error message but database is not initialized even if I suppress container and rebuilt

what is wrong with my docker-compose.yml file?

docker-compose.dev.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        restart: always
        container_name: coverage-africa-web-dev
        build: 
            context: ./app
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        restart: always
        command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./app:/usr/src/app
            - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdata.dev.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdata.dev.sql
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        env_file:
            - ./.env.dev
```

Comment: You're mounting the file into your application container, not the database container.

Comment: yes you are right... lost with my different environment...